# WEKA shows my first variable from the ARFF File starts with the characters ï»¿

Tags: excel, weka

In WEKA I tried to use an ARFF file as a test set for a model after classifying my training data (under the classify tab) but received the following error: "Train and test set are not compatible." See image:


[image: Train and test set are not compatible]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlnB6.png)


I opened both original training and test CSV files in Excel, and they looked the same to me. I opened the CSV files in Notepad++ and they looked the same to me. However, I opened the test ARFF in WEKA and found strange characters at the beginning of the the first attribute name. See image:


[image: Strange Characters (ï»¿) appear at the beginning of the first attribute name in WEKA]


Why are the strange characters there and how do I remove them? I need to have the training and test ARFF files be compatible for classification.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you used Excel for editing the test file:

See if you had saved the file under the file format "CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)" as opposed to the file format "CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)". Note the latter file format does not include "UTF-8".

If so, re-save the test CSV file in Excel in the latter file format (without the UTF-8) and made a new ARFF file from it. This time, WEKA should not show the "ï»¿" characters at the beginning of the first attribute.